# Questions with multiple close votes don't always show in "closed" mod tools

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, moderator-tools

The question [What's the best way to move to linux from windows for web development ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544685/whats-the-best-way-to-move-to-linux-from-windows-for-web-development) currently has four close votes, and has stayed at that number for almost its whole existence. With that many votes, I would expect that it would show up on the [close mod tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=close&daterange=last2days) page and quickly get that last vote.

However, the current votes are split between 2 "off topic" (migrate to P.SE) and 2 "not a real question". As a consequence, it doesn't show up in *either* of the corresponding categories on the mod tools because it only has two votes of each. Without that visibility, it's unlikely to get that final vote.

I suggest that the mod tools use the *total* number of close votes when sorting questions to show. This would cause questions such as the above to show up in two categories with 4 close votes each.

**Update**: After the mention here, the question got its final close vote. Of course, the situation described still needs attention.

Comment: I was unaware that vote count had anything to do with the visibility. Is it different for Stack Overflow compared to other places?

Comment: @Grace Note: Questions on the close page are sorted by close vote count, in descending order, with a limit of some total number of questions shown. SO has enough closed questions that questions with low close vote counts aren't always shown.

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes sense. Showing all 4 votes on the wrong category might be misleading, but that could be touched up by, say, adding a tooltip with the breakdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the next build, it will be ordered by the *combined* votes.